# How do I assign method name (or annotation element) strings in a way that is safe for refactoring?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, refactoring

Suppose I have a class `com.example.Foo` and another class `com.sample.Bar` which needs to know the fully-qualified name of `Foo`. If I am a Java novice I might put:

```
public class Bar {
    private String fooName = "com.example.Foo";
    //...
}
```

However, if I refactored `Foo` to change the name or package, the changes would not be reflected in `Bar`, unless the IDE is really clever. So it's better to do something like this:

```
import com.example.Foo;

public class Bar {
    private String fooName = Foo.class.getName();
    // ...
}
```

This way, if I refactor `Foo`, then the change should be picked up by `Bar`.

Now consider methods. If I have a method name in class `Foo` and the name needs to be known by `Bar`, it seems the best I can do is:

```
public class Bar {
    private String bazName = Foo.class.getMethod("bazMethod", Qux.class);
    // ...
}
```

But I haven't actually achieved anything - I still have a string literal "bazMethod" which won't be refactored if the real `bazMethod` gets renamed.

What I really want to do is something like:

```
public class Bar {
    private String bazName = tellMeTheMethodName((new Foo()).bazMethod(null));
    // ...
}
```

Not sure if this is possible somehow and if there is any way around it.

Now comes the real problem - even if you can sort that out as above, the real thing I am trying to access is an annotation attribute/element name. But annotations are abstract and cannot even be instantiated. So is this possible?

Comment: if you are using eclipse: It can replace non-code references to that class too (as long as you are using the fully qualified name). None-code meaning either a String, a comment or the content of any other file.

Comment: This only matters if you are calling `Foo` methods through reflection. Otherwise if you have regular method invocations in `Foo`, they will be refactored through your IDE's "change method signature" function, or will simply not compile if you manually change the method signature.

Comment: No, there's no compile time static way to reference a method by name.

Comment: can you elaborate on the "real problem"?

Comment: If you want to be absolutely sure that old code still works, create a new class, copy over all methods make the old class be full of delegates

Comment: @bayou.io The real problem is just what I stated, I'm not hiding anything. My point is that even if I could create a `tellMeTheMethodName` method for normal class methods, this still wouldn't work for annotation methods because annotations can't be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Annotation is just an interface, which you can subclass too! :) For example, annotation

```
public @interface SomeAnno
{
    String attr1();
    int    attr2();
}
```

And you want a "statically typed" way to reference names "attr1", "attr2".

This can be done through some elaborate conspiracies among some methods.

```
String n1 = name( SomeAnno::attr1 );

class MyAnno implements SomeAnno
{
    String attr1(){ ... }
```

`MyAnno.attr1()/attr2()/...` each triggers a distinct side effect; `name(action)` compares the side effect of the `action`, and matches it to one of the attr.

---

We can generalize this trick to write a universal util that works on any annotation type (actually, any interface type).

```
SomeAnno anno = proxy(SomeAnno.class);

String n1 = name( anno::attr1 );
```

---

But this is really not worth it:) You can just hardcode the name, and do a runtime check (as early as possible) to assert that the name is indeed valid.

Comment: I still don't quite understand. If `name` compares the side effects of the actions and matches them, then what does it return? I can't see any way around it returning a string literal, which would completely defeat the object of doing this. We would know what method it was called, but not its (refactor-safe) name. By the way, I'm using Java 7, so I also can't use lambdas ;)